# Solution of $\vec{p}-$Laplace equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, p-laplace

Let $\Omega  \subset {\mathbb{R}^n}$ is bounded domain with smooth boundary. We consider the bvp 
$$ - \sum\limits_{I = 1}^n {{\partial _{{x_i}}}\left( {{{\left| {{\partial _{{x_i}}}u} \right|}^{{p_i} - 2}}\partial {u_{{x_i}}}} \right)}  + {\left| u \right|^{q - 2}}u = f,\,x \in \Omega ,$$
with Dirichlet conditions ${\left. u \right|_{\partial \Omega }} = 0$, where ${p_i},\,q \in \left[ {2,\infty } \right)$. I tried to prove the existence of weak solution of bvp but i dont have any idea.